# Getting NoSuchMethodError exception on com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation.getAvdFolder() when trying to run "ionic cordova run --emulator"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, emulation, android-sdk-tools

I just upgraded my cordova and ionic (npm upgrade -g cordova ionic) and now when I run "ionic cordova run --emulator" I'm getting the following error message:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation.getAvdFolder()Ljava/lang/String;

The build is successful, it just doesn't seem to want to start the emulator.

Any help would be very appreciated.

---

Here is the end of the log after the successful build message:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.135 secs
Built the following apk(s):
    /Users/lesbuchanan/source/personal/sandbox/mobile/ionic/phone-vow/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/lesbuchanan/Library/Android/sdk/
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home
Error: avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation.getAvdFolder()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:380)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.getAvdManager(AvdManagerCli.java:338)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.displayAvdList(AvdManagerCli.java:516)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.doAction(AvdManagerCli.java:355)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:203)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:193)

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android --emulator (exit code 1).enter code here

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, I just used Android Studio to update the SDK tools.  Go to Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK, then click the SDK Tools tab.  I updated the following packages:

- Android SDK Build-Tools
- Android Emulator
- Android SDK Platform-Tools
- Android SDK Tools
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator
- Support Repository->Android Support Repository
- Support Repository->Google Repository

I'm honestly not sure which package solved my problem but I imagine updating all of them at the same time was a good idea.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: It definitely was `Android SDK Tools`, see my answer for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**
You've run into a jar hell issue, probably caused by the Android SDK patcher. The only thing that worked for me was to delete everything in the `ANDROID_HOME` directory and used IntelliJ IDEA's Android SDK manager (which Android Studio is built on top) and re-install Android SDK. Note that updating `Android SDK tools` might work, as it worked in [Les Buchanan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43950268/1051677) but it's more of a lucky fix for something that more often than not, it's caused by the SDK patcher itself.

**Long explanation:**
Ionic, Cordova, etc. build on top of what Android SDK offers. `cordova run --emulator` invokes `avdmanager` because you need an Android Virtual Device to emulate in the first place. So I've run it directly and still ran into OP's issue, clearly eliminating `cordova` and `ionic` from possible causes:

```
$ $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/avdmanager.bat
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation.getAvdFolder()Ljava/lang/String;
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.init(AvdManagerCli.java:278)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:210)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
```

If you look into the `andmanager.bat` file, you'll see that invokes AvdManagerCli main class around line 68-69:

```
@rem Execute avdmanager
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %AVDMANAGER_OPTS%  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

One line above it sets the `CLASSPATH` variable, which, among other things, includes this entry: `APP_HOME%\lib\common-26.0.0-dev.jar`. If you look inside it, e.g. unzip and open the `com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation` class, you'll notice that `getAvdFolder` method exists. Then why is it `avdmanager` complaining about it? When I've faced similar issues in the past, this usually meant that there are 2 or more versions of this class in the classpath and/or the class gets loaded from the incorrect and often outdated jar file.

Therefore, I wanted to see which jar is loaded for this class. Back to `avdmanager.bat` at line 68-69, added `-verbose:class` flag where `AvdManagerCli` is invoked with that `java` command above, and ran `avdmanager.bat` again, this time showing me the classes being loaded:

```
[Opened C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Object from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.Serializable from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Comparable from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar]
...
...
many
...
entries
...
ahead
...
[Loaded com.android.sdklib.util.CommandLineParser$Arg from file:/C:/Users/sburcea/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/sdklib-26.0.0-dev.jar]
[Loaded com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation from file:/C:/Users/sburcea/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/common.jar]
Exception in thread "main" [Loaded java.lang.Throwable$PrintStreamOrWriter from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$KeySet from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation.getAvdFolder()Ljava/lang/String;
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.init(AvdManagerCli.java:278)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:210)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
```

A-HA! So `com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation` was loaded from `ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/common.jar` which wasn't even mentioned in the classpath! Looking inside `ANDROID_HOME\lib\common.jar` revealed that it contains `com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation` class but it does NOT have `#getAvdFolder`. It was probably a leftover from the older SDKs that I had installed on my machine. I needed a clean-up anyway and deleted the folder and re-installed the Android SDK and the problem was gone. I still wanted to know which jar loads the `com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation` class and I've added the `-verbose:class` back in my `avdmanager.bat`:

```
$ /c/Users/sburcea/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager.bat | grep AndroidLocation
[Loaded com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException from file:/C:/Users/sburcea/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/common-26.0.0-dev.jar]
[Loaded com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation from file:/C:/Users/sburcea/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/common-26.0.0-dev.jar]
[Loaded com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation$Global from file:/C:/Users/sburcea/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/common-26.0.0-dev.jar]
```