# Meteor: Issue while Android App Configuration

Tags: android, meteor

I am new in this community and I want to develop some great stuff using meteor specifically for mobile devices but while adding platforms I got errors,

```
meteor add-platform android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib -
android: added platform
Status of the individual requirements:
✓ Java JDK
✓ Android SDK
✗ Android target: avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation.getAvdFolder()Ljava/lang/String;
at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.init(AvdManagerCli.java:278)
at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:210)
at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
✓ Gradle
```

I got the solition as start emulator first but that didn’t help.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: It looks like an expected method is missing from your Android Studio install, possibly because it's out of date. I think this is a likely solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949191/getting-nosuchmethoderror-exception-on-com-android-prefs-androidlocation-getavdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I got the solution as there are some bugs in the installed tools, So I downloaded android Sdk 24.3.4 and extract it and replaces my tools folder with the existing and things sorted out.

The problem exists in the Android SDK 25.