# Is it possible to create and maintain Android Virtual Devices WITHOUT installing Android Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, nativescript, android-virtual-device

The development I'm taking on is written in TypeScript/JavaScript, and all the instructions left behind use **TNS (Telerik NativeScript)** command lines to build, debug and publish the apps, for both Android and iOS.

Setting up my Windows PC with **Visual Studio Code**, **Node.js**, **NativeScript**, and the **Android SDK**, I have got to the point where I can build the application using `> tns build android` but I cannot run it as I have no devices.

Going back to the NativeScript instructions, it does clearly say that an **Android Virtual Device** is needed, but the link takes me to how to setup an AVD using **Android Studio**.

Well, I do not want to install another IDE just to be able to manage AVD's. I'm familiar with VS Code, all the original development was done in VS Code on iOS, and all the documentation, including screenshots, are from VS Code.

Supposedly, there is an AVDManager.exe in *C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\*, but there certainly isn't in my installation of the SDK.

`> emulator -list-avds` shows nothing.

`> tns device android --available-devices` also lists no available emulators.

Embarcaderos' RAD Studio includes an Android emulator, but I'm using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo for desktop development, so don't have access to that emulator on this machine.

Is there any other way to create an AVD, so that when I type `> tns run android` from the working folder of the mobile app, it starts the emulator and runs the app within it?

Comment: Windroid........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download just the SDK command line tools via [the android studio download page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) -> "Get just the command line tools". 
The `emulator` program and the [avdmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager.html) should be everything you need to get an emulator up and running.

Comment: Thank you. Scrolled down the Download Options and found the command line tools ZIP file for Windows.

Comment: Once extracted, I copied the contents of the tools folder over the contents of my existing C:\Android\android-sdk\tools folder. Now there is an avdmanager.bat I can use.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when trying to create the AVD. This is the same error as reported by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949191/getting-nosuchmethoderror-exception-on-com-android-prefs-androidlocation-getavdf, but his answer was to reinstall the SDK Tools from Android Studio. Well, I have only just installed the tools, and rebooted the PC.

Comment: Turns out you can't just copy the contents over the existing tools folder. You have to completely remove the old tools folder and its subfolders, then copy in the contents of the ZIP file.

Comment: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/12/manually-setup-nativescript-without-provided-scripts/

Might outline a way to get what you're looking for

Comment: Eventually I got it working, after a lot of retries, re-installs and copying of various folders. From what I read putting all this together, there are some design problems in the latest Google SDK that require various workarounds. Some of these problems exist even if you are using Android Studio.